# Storing Tree Structures in Loopback - Can loopback support hierarchical data?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

How can I store the following tree structure in Loopback.io

```
FolderItem{
      String name;
      ArrayList<Images> images;
      ArrayList<String> comments;
      ArrayList<FolderItems> items;
}
```

or if possible

```
FolderItem{
     MyData myData;   // 1-1
     ArrayList<FolderItem>  items;  // 0-n
}
```

Where

```
  MyData{
     String name;
     ArrayList<Images> images;
     ArrayList<String> comments;
}
```

How can I store the folder structure in Loopback model?  Can loopback strongloop support a tree hierarchical model?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is quite a good question. One way to answer it would be to create a `someModel` `hasMany` `someModel` relation (model relates to itself).

Using the strongloop command line :

1. Create a `FolderItem` model, and add a property `name`
2. Create a relation `FolderItem` `hasMany` `FolderItem`
3. Start your server, and using the api explorer make a `POST api\FolderItem` to create a first FolderItem
4. then, create a child item with `POST api\FolderItem\1\folderItems\`

You will be able to build a tree like that, however you will need to implement tree traversal methods (which I suppose you do need).

I have never tried it, but I suppose you can make a relation on model toward itself without trouble. Please let me know the result, this is interesting.

PS : If your final goal is to describe a folder hierarchy, you might be better off using a globally-unique id for each folder, and ditch the entire hierarchy altogether. This is pretty much what is done in all cloud-based storage services. Just sayin

Comment: Interesting suggestions.  Ok, I will try some of these approaches

Comment: Sure, don't hesitate to comment back if you have made some edits/progress.

Comment: Hey could you elaborate on the globally-unique id approach.  I would like to understand this approach better.   Would this not still be a many to many relationship between the same type of entity of folder?

Comment: a hasMany for storing the childs and hasOne for storing the parent. Not ManyToMany because in a tree a node can have multiple childs but a child has always a single parent